# Generic controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Can you explain to me the point of a controller when all it does it return a view? Have I missed the point here?

I've come across a situation when trying to build a rudimentary CMS where the user can create views (stored in the database), but of course as they are user created, the controller's don't exist. So is there another way to serve them?

Thanks for any help, I'm still trying to get to grips with MVC fully!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can you explain to me the point of a controller when all it does it return a view?

Who said that all a controller does is to return a view? A controller does lots of other things. For example it could receive the user input under the form of an action parameters, check whether the ModelState.IsValid, do some processing on the Model and then return a View which is the whole point of the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

> I've come across a situation when trying to build a rudimentary CMS
>   where the user can create views (stored in the database), but of
>   course as they are user created, the controller's don't exist. So is
>   there another way to serve them?

Yes, of course. You could use a [custom virtual path provider](http://blog.rocketbase.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-virtual-path-provider/) by implementing the [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) class.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstand me, my apologies. I meant, when a controller just returns a view, is that a bit overkill? Is there a way to render a view without the controller?

Comment: Sorry also, I am already using VirtualPathProvider to store the views, that's great, but how to render them when no Controller exists as the user has "only" created the view part?

Comment: You cannot render a view without a controller. This goes against the MVC pattern. Don't use the ASP.NET MVC framework if you don't want to follow this pattern. You could have a single controller which renders a view with a given name so that your custom virtual path provider resolves from the database.

Comment: I understand the pattern, just was wondering if it was normal to have a controller that all it did was "return View();". Thanks for answering my question! :)